# python socket multi-threading with docker issue

Tags: python, django, multithreading, docker

The program I am write is quite simple, just use python struct to create an ICMP ping packet, then use socket to send out, measure the latency.

Do not want system level command because I am trying to make this independent beyond whichever OS is deploying the code.

Here is part of the code:

```
    def _icmp_ping(host, packet_size, interval, timeout, packet_num):
        # Sends ICMP echo requests to the specified host and returns the average latency and success rate as a tuple
        if packet_size < 8:
            packet_size = 8
        payload = b'\x00' * (packet_size-8)
        icmp_protocol = socket.getprotobyname("icmp")
        icmp_echo = 8
        packet_id = random.randint(1, 0xffff)
        packet = struct.pack("!BBHHH", icmp_echo, 0, 0, packet_id, 1) + payload
        # Adds the ICMP checksum to the packet
        packet = struct.pack("!BBHHH", icmp_echo, 0, socket.htons(NetPack._calculate_checksum(packet)), packet_id, 1) + payload

        sent_count = 0
        received_count = 0
        total_latency = 0

        # Sends 10 ICMP echo requests
        for _ in range(packet_num):
            # Creates a raw socket for sending ICMP packets
            with closing(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, icmp_protocol)) as sock:
                # Sets the timeout for the socket
                sock.settimeout(timeout)
                # Sends the ICMP packet to the specified host
                sock.sendto(packet, (host, 1))

                # Records the start time and counts the packets being sent out.
                sent_count += 1
                start_time = time.time()

                try:
                    # Receives the ICMP response from the host
                    _, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
                    end_time = time.time()
                    # Calculates the latency and counts the received packets
                    received_count += 1
                    total_latency += end_time - start_time
                except socket.timeout:
                    # If no response is received within the timeout period, ignores the packet
                    pass

                # Waits for the specified interval before sending the next packet
                time.sleep(max(0, interval - (time.time() - start_time)))

        # Calculates the average latency and success rate
        return (total_latency / received_count) * 1000 if received_count > 0 else None, received_count / sent_count * 100

    def ping(host, packet_size=64, protocol="icmp", interval=0.2, timeout=1, packet_num=5):
        # Try to get address information for the given host
        try:
            socket.getaddrinfo(host, None, socket.AF_INET6)
            address_family = socket.AF_INET6  # Use IPv6 address family if available
        except socket.gaierror:
            address_family = socket.AF_INET  # Otherwise, use IPv4 address family

        # Depending on the protocol, call the corresponding ping function
        if protocol.lower() == "icmp":
            # ICMP protocol is only supported for IPv4
            if address_family == socket.AF_INET6:
                raise ValueError("ICMP is not supported for IPv6 addresses in this implementation.")
            return NetPack._icmp_ping(host, packet_size, interval, timeout, packet_num)
        elif protocol.lower() == "tcp":
            # Use TCP protocol for both IPv4 and IPv6
            return NetPack._tcp_ping(host, packet_size, interval, timeout, packet_num)
        else:
            # Raise an error if an unsupported protocol is given
            raise ValueError("Unsupported protocol. Please use 'icmp' or 'tcp'.")

    def multiple_ping(hosts, packet_size=64, protocol="icmp", interval=0.2, timeout=1, packet_num=5):
        multiping_results = {}

        # Define a function to ping a host and store the result in the results dictionary
        def ping_host(ip):
            latency, success_rate = NetPack.ping(ip, packet_size, protocol, interval, timeout, packet_num)
            multiping_results[ip] = {'success_rate': success_rate, 'latency': latency}

        # Create a thread for each host and start them all simultaneously
        threads = []
        for host in hosts:
            t = threading.Thread(target=ping_host, args=(host,))
            threads.append(t)
            t.start()

        # Wait for all threads to finish before returning the results dictionary
        for t in threads:
            t.join()
```

The above is the code in the backend that supports the ping message. I even packet this up as a packet as netpackAIO in pypi. I called it in my django env and run it like.

```
def ping_result(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        ip_list = IPList.objects.get(number=functions.get_ip_address(request))
        ip_list = str(ip_list.ip_list_string).split(',')
        multiping_results = func.NetPack.multiple_ping(ip_list)

        return render(request, './templates/ping_result.html', {'result': multiping_results})
```

The ip_list is just a group of IP in strings.

Here is the issue,

if I run my website under regular env (like python manage.py runserver), result will be fine and correct.
For example:

> If I ping 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.8.9 at the same time, 8.8.8.8 will return reachable with an avg latency and 8.8.8.9 will return as timeout/unreachable.

If I run the website in docker, the result will be look as follow.

> If I ping 8.8.8.9, it will show as timeout/unreachable
> If I ping 8.8.8.8, it will show as reachable with an avg latency.
> **If I ping 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.8.9 at the same time, both 8.8.8.8, 8.8.8.9 is reachable and the latency is pretty much the same as the 8.8.8.8 one.**

Online solution was to run docker with `--net=host`, which is not work. I also think the multi-thread thing is not working but turn out to be that the program itself actually create 2 session for the ping. I also suspect the `sock.recv` is share the same buffer and mixed up the icmp reply. But I got no way to differentiate that.

I have a feeling that the docker itself has some mechanism that is mixing the receiving buffer to recognize the reply for 8.8.8.8 as the same as 8.8.8.9 even though 8.8.8.9 is timeout.

Please, any kind of advise is appreciated.

Update:

I also re-write the OS version ping, the result is the same. Issue still exist, I would say it's not the socket's issue.

Comment: Just want to add that, if I remove the multithreading and use a for loop to run the ping one by one, the result is also correct when I am using docker.

Comment: `_, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)` This will receive *any* ICMP packet. You need to that its specifically an ICMP echo reply, that it came from the right IP address, and that it has the same identifier as the one you sent.

Comment: @NickODell  I am using a different thread, also I have said that if I run my program in python virtualenv, thing would work. The only issue is run this in docker which is weird.